# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Sorting Algorithm Visualiser")
root.geometry("1500x780+0+0")
root.config(bg="#D7DBDD")
```

**canvas**

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg="#F8F9F9").pack()
```

**rectangle on canvas**
*what is error here*

```
canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red")

root.mainloop()
```

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VINAYAK/PycharmProjects/try/try o1.py", line 10, in 
    canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'

Process finished with exit code 1*

Comment: ``Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg="#F8F9F9").pack()`` will return `None`,You should use ``canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg="#F8F9F9")`` and ``canvas.pack()``

Comment: its working.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you can't create and pack your canvas at the same time.
this should work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Sorting Algorithm Visualiser")
root.geometry("1500x780+0+0")
root.config(bg="#D7DBDD")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=500, bg="#F8F9F9")

canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red")

canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```